# blockread(); и blockwrite(); в Turbo Pascal

Tags: pascal, файлы

Изучаю тему "Файлы".

Поняла, что процедуры blockread(); и blockwrite(); используются для буферезированного ввода/вывода считываемых блоков записи при работе с нетипизированными файлами.

С помощью blockread(); происходит запись в буфер из файла.

С помощью blockwrite(); происходит запись из буфера в файл.

Указано, что при этом пользователь сам может определить размер буфера для файловых операций и это особенно нужно при жестком планировании ресурсов.

Уважаемые профессионалы, прошу, если я где-то ошиблась, поправьте меня, пожалуйста.

Далее.

Теория - теорией. Но в учебном пособии не приводится ни одного примера, как и когда можно использовать эти процедуры.

Пожалуйста, приведите примеры ситуаций, КОГДА нужно использовать данные процедуры и, самое главное, КАК это нужно делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти процедуры могут использоваться при копировании файлов разного типа (текстовый файл можно скопировать и при помощи обычных ReadLn и WriteLn). Вот пример:

```
Var
  f1, f2: File;
  cop: Byte;
begin
  Assign(f1, '1.jpg');
  Assign(f2, '2.jpg');
  ReSet(f1);
  Rewrite(f2);
  Cop:=255;
  While Not(Eof(f1)) Do
          Begin
            BlockRead(f1, cop, 1);
            BlockWrite(f2, cop, 1);
          End;
  Close(f1);
  Close(f2);
end.
```

Программа копирует изображение.

Answer (score 2):

При использовании blockwrite данные сохраняются точно в том формате, в котором они хранились в памяти, к примеру, целое число не будет переводиться в десятичный код и будет всегда занимать в файле ровно 4 байта, независимо от количества цифр числа в десятичной системе.

Точно также числа с плавающией точкой будут занимать в файле фиксированное число байт и не будет терять знаки после запятой при переводе в десятичную систему и округлении при записи, и обратно в двоичную при загрузке из файла, как обычно происходит при работе с текстовыми файлами.

Еще один плюс - можно сохранять запись (record) целиком за один прием, а не записывать каждое поле записи по отдельности. Также можно записывать целый массив одним блоком, не используя цикл.

Еще одно свойство двоичных файлов - открыв такой файл в текстовом редакторе трудно что-то понять и отредактировать, ничего случайно не "сломав", т.е. не испортив хранящиеся в нем данные. Для ручного редактирования двоичных файлов предназначены [хекс-редакторы](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HEX-%F0%E5%E4%E0%EA%F2%EE%F0).

P.S. Где это может понадобиться - там где нужно более плотное хранение данных (чем обычный текстовый формат) и не требуется чтобы любой желающий мог легко что-то в файле изменить. Примеры:

1. Исполняемые файлы
2. Системные файлы
3. Изображения
4. Архивы
5. Файлы сохранений игр :)
6. Документы со сложными данными
7. Файлы с зашифрованными данными

и т.д.